# Structuring Wordpress PHP Redirect Plugin

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm attempting to create a very basic plugin to use for redirects on my Wordpress pages that detect if a user is logged in or not. I'm able to get just the if statement working, but I'm adding the else statement and not sure what part of the syntax I have wrong that creates a fatal error:

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Three Dot Redirects
*/

add_action('wp_head', 'rhombus_gate_redirect');
function rhombus_gate_redirect() { 
    if (is_page('rhombus_gate') && is_user_logged_in()) {
    wp_redirect ( home_url("/constructs/pizza") );
    }
    else (is_page('rhombus_gate')) {
    wp_redirect ( home_url("/gate") );
    }

}
```

Comment: What exactly is the error?

Answer (score 1):

The `wp_head` action hook is too late to redirect, as headers have already been sent.

Instead, I recommend using the [`template_redirect` hook](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/template_redirect), which fires after WordPress has finished loading but before any headers are sent. The user is authenticated at this stage, and the page template is determined.

`else` also doesn't take a condition...and `wp_redirect()` should **always** be followed by `exit`:

```
add_action('template_redirect', 'rhombus_gate_redirect');
function rhombus_gate_redirect() { 
    if ( is_page('rhombus_gate') ) {
        $redirect_url = is_user_logged_in() ? home_url("/constructs/pizza") : home_url("/gate");
        wp_redirect ( $redirect_url );
        exit;
    }
}
```